# Prism 6 get ShellViewModel Context inside other viewModel

Tags: prism

I'm currently working on WPF App with Prism 6...I have `ShellViewModel`, `ViewAViewModel` and `ViewBViewModel`.

Inside `Shell.xaml`, I have `"mainRegion"` defined. When app is started, I show `ViewA` in that Region by default.

Now, When I go to from `ViewA` to `ViewB`, at this point(Inside `ViewBViewModel`), I need to have context of `ShellViewModel`.

Any suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: why you need the ShellViewModel ? can you provide more informations ?

Comment: My main screen (Shell.xaml) consists of two parts
(i.) Ribbon tab (To show menus)
(ii.) Region Manager provided  by prism

So, depending on Ribbon tab clicked, Region Manager will show appropiate Views(Usercontrols...)
Suppose, I hv two views
(i) ViewA --> showing List
(ii.) ViewB  --> showing form

User can go from ViewA to ViewB through Edit button...So I need to show respective tab selected accordingly...
So will be requing ShellContext in my ViewBViewModel so that i can set tab's "IsSelected" property accordingly

Answer (score 0):

the full source code!

**ViewA.xaml**

`<UserControl x:Class="ModuleA.Views.ViewA"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"

             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="38" />
            <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Width="100">Update</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>`

**ViewA.xaml.cs**

```
using ModuleA.RibbonTabs;
using PrismDemo.Core;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace ModuleA.Views
{
  [RibbonTab(typeof(ViewATab))]
  public partial class ViewA : UserControl, ISupportDataContext
  {
    public ViewA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

**ViewB.xaml**

`<UserControl x:Class="ModuleA.Views.ViewB"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"

             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="38" />
            <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Width="100">Update</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>`

**ViewB.xaml.cs**

```
using ModuleA.RibbonTabs;
using PrismDemo.Core;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace ModuleA.Views
{
[RibbonTab(typeof(ViewBTab))]
//the main view can inject any number of tab 
//uncomment the following lines and test
//I added the same tab just for demo purposes
//[RibbonTab(typeof(ViewBTab))]
//[RibbonTab(typeof(ViewBTab))]
//[RibbonTab(typeof(ViewBTab))]
public partial class ViewB : UserControl, ISupportDataContext
{
    public ViewB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

**ModuleAModule.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using ModuleA.Views;
using Prism.Modularity;
using Prism.Unity;

namespace ModuleA
{
    public class ModuleAModule : IModule
    {
        IUnityContainer _container;

        public ModuleAModule(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            //register for nav
            _container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA>();
            _container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewB>();
        }
    }
}
```

**RibbonTabAttribute.cs**

```
using System;

namespace PrismDemo.Core
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class RibbonTabAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public Type Type { get; private set; }

        public RibbonTabAttribute(Type ribbonTabType)
        {
            Type = ribbonTabType;
        }
    }
}
```

**ISupportDataContext.cs**

```
namespace PrismDemo.Core
{
    public interface ISupportDataContext
    {
        object DataContext { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**bootstrapper.cs**

```
using Prism.Unity;
using PrismDemo.Views;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Prism.Modularity;
using ModuleA;
using Prism.Regions;
using PrismDemo.Prism;
using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;

namespace PrismDemo
{
    class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        var catalog = (ModuleCatalog)ModuleCatalog;
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleAModule));
    }

    protected override IRegionBehaviorFactory ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors()
    {
        var behaviors = base.ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors();
        behaviors.AddIfMissing(RibbonRegionBehavior.BehaviorKey, typeof(RibbonRegionBehavior));
        return behaviors;
    }
   }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="PrismDemo.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrismDemo">
<Application.Resources>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
namespace PrismDemo
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            var bs = new Bootstrapper();
            bs.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Shell.xaml**

```
<Window  x:Class="PrismDemo.Views.Shell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
Title="Shell" Height="720" Width="1280">
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Ribbon Grid.Row="0" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RibbonTabRegion"/>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="1">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Navigate ViewA" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ViewA" />
        <Button Content="Navigate ViewB" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ViewB" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" Margin="1,3,3,3" />
</DockPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Shell.xaml.cs**

```
namespace PrismDemo.Views
{
    public partial class Shell 
    {
        public Shell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Regions;

namespace PrismDemo.ViewModels
{
public class ShellViewModel : BindableBase
{
    IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; }

    public ShellViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;

        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
    }

    void Navigate(string navigationPath)
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", navigationPath);
    }
}
}
```

**RibbonRegionBehavior.cs**

```
using Prism.Regions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using PrismDemo.Core;
using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;

namespace PrismDemo.Prism
{
public class RibbonRegionBehavior : RegionBehavior
{
    public const string BehaviorKey = "RibbonRegionBehavior";

    public const string RibbonTabRegionName = "RibbonTabRegion";

    protected override void OnAttach()
    {
        if (Region.Name == "ContentRegion")
            Region.ActiveViews.CollectionChanged += ActiveViews_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void ActiveViews_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            var tabList = new List<RibbonTab>();

            foreach (var newView in e.NewItems)
            {
                foreach (var atr in GetCustomAttributes<RibbonTabAttribute>(newView.GetType()))
                {
                    var ribbonTabItem = Activator.CreateInstance(atr.Type) as RibbonTab;

                    if (ribbonTabItem is ISupportDataContext && newView is ISupportDataContext)
                        ((ISupportDataContext)ribbonTabItem).DataContext = ((ISupportDataContext)newView).DataContext;

                    tabList.Add(ribbonTabItem);
                }

                tabList.ForEach(x => Region.RegionManager.Regions[RibbonTabRegionName].Add(x));
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            var views = Region.RegionManager.Regions[RibbonTabRegionName].Views.ToList();
            views.ForEach(x => Region.RegionManager.Regions[RibbonTabRegionName].Remove(x));
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> GetCustomAttributes<T>(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true).OfType<T>();
    }
 }
}
```

and this is the structure of the demo app:
[image: Structure of the demo app]

**this solution was provided by Brian Lagunas (prism owner) in his Pluralsight course (Prism Problems & Solutions: Loading Dependent Views), ** **There is another solution for this problem provided (again) by brian, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xH6OgCxdXQc, but I think the first solution is the best and the simplest**

**the view injected in the content region can injects any number of tabs, see comment in ViewB.xaml.cs**

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
  Will you be able to share above working code in zipped file As I dont have plural sight account and above code giving some error.

Comment: the solution works perfectly, and this is the link to download the demo project : https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=576726C17319C174!1229&authkey=!AE9MO4QC77LR7jM&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: Great Man :) Thanks a lot !. I will check solution.

Comment: Is there a way to get existing VMs using the IoC container (in my case DryIoc)? I tried `this == _Container.Resolve<ShellViewModel>` from the `ShellViewModel` and it evaluated to `false`.

Comment: You provided a project answer, to a simple question.